# how to use app from github

Tags: python, django, github

I have an app from Github.
I'm about to include that app and use it for practice

this is my  installed apps, I have run it  from comand prompt. I have added

```
app "shop_simplevariations"
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'jhapp',
    'shop_simplevariations',
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of stacktraces or error messages. Instead, copy the messages as text and directly include them here.

Comment: We can clone applications from github, please can you explain what do you mean by "dump app form github". You cannot include any applications which is on github and not on your machine.

Comment: This question shows little research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [github page](https://github.com/chrisglass/django-shop-simplevariations):

> This requires django SHOP to work
>   (https://github.com/chrisglass/django-shop)

You don't have `django-shop` installed. Once you have downloaded and added it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, make sure you run `python manage.py syncdb` so that the tables/fixtures are loaded.

Comment: how could i  insatll  django-shop .plz guide im  new to  this

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the github documentation .

For every project or application they provide a url which is read only .

To clone that on your system

You should try `clone` command

```
git clone https://yoururlorepository
```

Hope this will help you

If you using on the windows .

Install `git` for windows and from Git cli you can try with above command

**Update**

From your track back it seems that you are trying to use a app which is not yest installed in your application .

Things to check.

1. Check you have application name in your `INSTALLED_APPS` or not.

Still if you are getting some problem share the repo url .

Comment: Maybe he should check his model because the error caught there

Comment: @catherine you are right but i posted answer based on title of the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to install the app in your settings and in urlconf. Don't forgot also to check if there is init.py

Comment: will  you plz check  once my  upadated  question  i have added app  to  my  settings . still im  getting  same error